# Feedback on method of p-value

Tags: probability, statistics

I have the following problem:

*There is probability pp that a computer chip made by a certain company is defective. You want to test the hypothesis p<0.43 against the null hypothesis p=0.43. In order to do this you test 12 chips and you decide to reject the null hypothesis if the number of defective chips is at most 3.*

There is no answer shown, but I want to know if I'm doing it correctly:

I see type I error, that is the same as the p-value

Step 1. I recognize this dataset as a binomial distribution

Step 2. I caclulate the mean and variance with $E[X] = np = 5.16$ and $Var(X) = np(1-p) = 3.215$

step 3. The p-value is the probability to achieve this data or "more extreme" data. More extreem would mean that there are more than 3 chips defective.

Step 4. $Z>\frac{3-5.16}{\sqrt{\frac{3.2148}{12}}}$

Step 5. $Z>-4.1731$, so that means that the p-value is around 1, that seems highly unlikely.

Can I get some feedback??

Thanks

Comment: What p-value are you even calculating? Type 1 error (probability) is not the same as p-value. I don't see any type 1 error probability either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exercise requests to calculate the size of the test, say $\alpha$.

$$\alpha=\mathbb{P}[\sum_{i=1}^{12}X_i \leq 3|p=0.43]=0.1671$$

This is easy to be calculated using the exact Binomial Distribution.

$$\alpha=\sum_{k=0}^{3}\binom{12}{k}0.43^k\cdot0.57^{12-k}$$

If  you want to estimate this value with the Gaussian approx via CLT, the statistic to be calculated is

$$Z=\frac{3.5-12\cdot0.43}{\sqrt{12\cdot0.43\cdot0.57}}\approx -0.9679$$

getting a probabiliy of

$$\alpha=\mathbb{P}[Z<-0.9679]\approx 0.1665$$

As you can see, the approx result is very similar to the exact probability.

Comment: Thanks for the elaborate explaination! What I noticed it that when using the CLT the denominator of the fraction cointains *sqrt(n) when calculating a standarised sum and / sqrt(n) when  calulating a standarised mean. In your explaination, you didn't use the n factor, you took the root of the variance. Why didn't you divide by the root of n in the denominator?

Comment: Could that be because the experiment is not repeated. Say that the experiment was repated r times and 3 would be the mean value. Does that mean that the fraction becomes (3.5 - 12*0.43) / (sqrt(12*0.43*0.57)/sqrt(r))?

Comment: If that is the case I think I understand why

Comment: The 3,5 comes as a continuity correction factor.  $(3+0.5)$. To use the n factor you need to divide numerator and denominator by $n$. The result is the same...there are different versions of CLT

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{\sum_i X_i-n p }{\sqrt{np(1-p)}}=\frac{\overline{X}- p }{\sqrt{p(1-p)}} \sqrt{n}$$

Comment: This belongs as an edit, not an answer.